# Google cloud datastore getting a list containing items

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I'm currently learning google cloud datastore, endpoints, and NDB models. I've done pretty well for myself so far(complete newbie programmer), and ran into an issue. I have a property that is a string which contains keywords I want to use for a search. example; toast,bagel,white,dark.

My Query currently pulls an exact string match, but I want it to do a partial string match as well.  Code below does work, but it seems the IN statement is still looking for exact matches. Anyway to tell datastore what the delimiter is for a property to read each word individually? or should I be splitting it out into 4 different property fields?

```
 if len(search) == 4:
        for task in DirectionModel.query(DirectionModel.keywords == request.keywords, namespace='cookingDirections'):
            tasks.append(Direction(name=task.name, direction=task.direction, description=task.description,
                                   keywords=task.keywords))
    else:
        for task in DirectionModel.query(DirectionModel.keywords.IN([search]), namespace='cookingDirections'):
            tasks.append(Direction(name=task.name, direction=task.direction, description=task.description,
                                   keywords=task.keywords))
    return DirectionList(items=tasks)
```

Model:

```
class DirectionModel(ndb.Model):
name = ndb.StringProperty()
direction = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
description = ndb.StringProperty()
keywords = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Comment: Updated to Add Model.

Comment: You should use an Array property (Array of Strings) to store the keywords. Then you can search for any of the keywords or a combination of keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [repeated property](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#repeated) for this.

```
class DirectionModel(ndb.Model):

    ...
    keywords = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
```

And query like this

```
DirectionModel.query(DirectionModel.Keywords.IN(['toast', 'bagel', 'white', 'dark'])
```

This assumes you're matching lists of strings against lists of strings.

Be aware that these kinds of queries can lead to [exploding indexes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/indexes), so if you are going to do complex keyword searches you may be better off investigating the [Search API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try

Comment: Works! I had to do some Type conversion, and update my datastore entries. however if I do toast,bagel it still pulls  toast,bread,white,medium. However, I think that just a matter of working on my logic!

Comment: `IN` operator checks to see if any of the stored keywords is in the list you provide.